# Altering another document in Doctrine ODM PreUpdate event

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, doctrine-odm

Fairly new at MongoDB and Doctrine both. I'm currently setting up a model system for my framework, and trying to implement the events.

The idea is this: When a certain model gets updated, a new user (also a model) should be created/updated. I do this all in the PreUpdate event so I can catch the changes made (check if the e-mail address on the model has been changed).

Creating and persisting a new model in this event works like a charm, however when I try to update a user I'm unable to save the data. I tried flushing but this causes an infinite loop (which I can understand why, as he tries to flush the same document again).

Any ideas on what way I should get this done? Tried recomputeSingleDocumentChangeSet on the unit of work for the user, but this doesn't seem to save anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Tried recomputeSingleDocumentChangeSet on the unit of work for the user, but this doesn't seem to save anything.

This is exactly what you should do (after modifying the user field)

```
$user->setSomething(true);
$uow->recomputeSingleDocumentChangeSet(/* ... */);
```

and nothing else, especially don't use `flush` as you are inside `flush` already. The `recomputeSingleDocumentChangeSet` makes Doctrine recount changes which will be later included in the update query of document.

> Creating and persisting a new model in this event works like a charm

This however sounds strange as new objects persisted at the time of `preUpdate` event should not reach database (unless you have issued another `flush` which may have unwanted side effects at this point) as insertions are handled before updates.

Comment: Going to mark this as an answer because of the good explanation. Unfortunately this didn't help in my case and I have solved it in a completely different way. But hey, technology, right? :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this issue by recalculating the UnitOfWork-Changeset after having changed the respective field value.

Without this ChangeSet recalculation, only fields that are already scheduled to update are taken into account. Any additional changes via $entity->setField() will be ignored whereas attempts to directly use $eventArgs->setNewValue($field, $value) will result in an error, as the latter only accepts modifications of values which are already part of the current UnitOfWork - change set.

You can trigger this operation via:

```
/** @var ObjectManager $em */
$om = $args->getObjectManager();
$om->getUnitOfWork()->recomputeSingleDocumentChangeSet($om->getClassMetadata($entity::class), $entity);
```